# Confusion About Reciprocal Lattice and Allowed Miller Indices

Tags: solid-state-physics, diffraction, braggs-law

We discussed in class that for a given crystal, say with a triangular lattice of spacing $a=2$ angstroms, it follows from the Ewald construction that there should exist a maximum wavelength of incoming radiation beyond which Bragg diffraction cannot occur as the Ewald sphere cannot intersect any reciprocal lattice vectors because its radius is too short. My confusion is in how to actually find this maximum wavelength and then the Bragg angles that occur at this wavelength.

I know that from Bragg's Law $\lambda<2d$, where $d$ is the inter-planar distance which is equal to $\frac{2\pi}{|G|}$. So for a given space lattice the magnitude of the reciprocal lattice vector $G$ depends on $h,k,l$ the Miller indices. For the triangular lattice for example, this works out to be: $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}a}\sqrt{4h^2+k^2-2hk}$. So do I take the $d$ where $\sqrt{4h^2+k^2-2hk}$ has its minimal value of $1$ or is there some other way to proceed?

Furthermore, if I take this wavelength of $2\sqrt{3}a$ and then plug it into the diffraction condition I still need conditions on which $h,k,l$ values are allowed to be used in Bragg's law. Can I find these from the condition that $2k_o^2(1-cos\Omega)=|G|^2$ ($k_0 =2\pi/\lambda$, $\Omega$ is the angle between the incident and diffracted wavevectors) and $cos\Omega\leq{1}$ and then plug the results into the diffraction condition $k-k'=G$ where $k$ is the incident wavevector and $k'$ is the diffracted beam's wavevector?